# AccessText inside Label (XAML to C#)

Tags: c#, xaml

The following code is part of a small XAML application that displays data in a tabular form. Basically I need to translate this code into C#.

```
<Grid Width="768" Height="1056">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="114" />
        <RowDefinition Height="906*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="36" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
...
<Label Grid.Row="1" Width="40" Height="32" Margin="14,4,0,0" Padding="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" Name="label16">
    <AccessText Margin="0,0,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" TextAlignment="Center" FontWeight="Bold">
        SEQ
    </AccessText>
</Label>
...
</Grid>
```

I've been looking for an answer for a couple of days and I can't find anything specific to this. Can someone please give me an idea of how to do it?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I constructed a sample `Window` for you. Here is the code-behind you are looking for:

```
public Window1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    AccessText text = new AccessText()
    {
        Text = "SEQ",
        Margin = new Thickness(0),
        TextWrapping = TextWrapping.Wrap,
        TextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center,
        FontWeight = FontWeights.Bold
    };

    Label label = new Label()
    {
        Content = text,
        Width = 40,
        Height = 32,
        Margin = new Thickness(14, 4, 0, 0),
        HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left,
        VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top,
        HorizontalContentAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center,
        VerticalContentAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center,
        BorderBrush = Brushes.Black,
        BorderThickness = new Thickness(1),
        Name = "label16"
    };

    Grid grid = new Grid();
    grid.Width = 768;
    grid.Height = 1056;
    grid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition() { Height = new GridLength(114) });
    grid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition() { Height = new GridLength(906, GridUnitType.Star) });
    grid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition() { Height = new GridLength(36) });
    Grid.SetRow(label, 1);
    grid.Children.Add(label);

    this.Content = grid;
}
```

This example nicely demonstrates how easy XAML is for constructing user interfaces. :)

Comment: Thank you, Charlie. It's an excelent example you posted. And it works indeed in a WPF application for Windows and WPF browser application as well. As soon as I try it in an ASP.NET application, nothing shows up. This ASP.NET application builds an XPS document (FixedDocument) on the server and then sends it as a stream to the client for viewing. Is there something I'm not aware of related to XPS (FixedDocument) or ASP.NET? I really appreciate your help.

Comment: I am not entirely sure about ASP.NET, as that is not my area of expertise. You could try asking about that in a separate question. Also, you should accept my answer if it helped you out! :)

Comment: The code works fine in ASP.NET as well. There was a bug in my code that was stopping the application display the text. Thank you again.